# Sending Post method manually using Python

Tags: python, post

I want to send a post request using python for some specific reason.
To be more specific i want to sent '12064608' into "code national" in this website http://bac.menara.ma/ministere/ .

The problem is that if I send it manually the respond is not the same as if we send enter '12064608' into the input . I found a lot of python peace of codes to do it but I figure out that the problem is in the Post method it self.
this is my code:

```
    import requests
    data = requests.post('http://bac.menara.ma/ministere/', {'txt1': 12064608 , 'texte2' : '%2324po8%23%234'})
    print data.text
```

to illustrate:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckkfl.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/). Using a `requests.session` makes it easy to keep track of the cookies, which you must obtain with an initial visit. Note that the form contains a hidden field that might change. I haven't observed it changing, but if you need you can extract it from the form using [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), or a regex in a pinch.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = requests.session()
r = s.get('http://bac.menara.ma/ministere/')    # go to form page, get cookies and "hidden" form field

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
texte2 = soup.find('input', attrs={'name': 'texte2'})['value']

data = {'txt1': '12345678', 'texte2': texte2}
r = s.post('http://bac.menara.ma/ministere/resultat.jsp', data=data)
html = r.content
assert 'Nom ; ELOUARDI ASSIA' in html
```

If you don't need to use `requests`, [`mechanize`](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) is easier to use because it will take care of both the cookies and any hidden form fields:

```
from mechanize import Browser

br = Browser()
r = br.open('http://bac.menara.ma/ministere')
br.select_form(nr=0)
# print br.form    # displays form fields and target URL
br.form['txt1'] = '12345678'
r = br.submit()
html = r.read()
assert 'Nom ; ELOUARDI ASSIA' in html
```

Comment: The post for `txt1` should be `12064608`

Comment: @heinst : it's just an example.

Comment: an other question how can i extract just the number in the 12345678 example 09.8

Comment: Use BeautifulSoup (or another HTML parser), e.g. `soup = BeautifulSoup(html);  t = soup.find('span', class_='mess-lance'); votre_note = t.text.split(';')[-1].strip()` Or use a regular expression like `votre_note = re.search('Votre Note ; (.*?)<br>', html).groups()[0]`.

Comment: Sorry for all these questions but i'm using it recursively until it retuns this message :                `r = s.get('http://bac.menara.ma/ministere/')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests-2.7.0-py2.7.egg\requests\sessions.py", line 477, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)`

Answer (score 0):

You may need to do it manually every once in a while to get a new `JSESSIONID` as it could expire.

```
import requests

url = "http://bac.menara.ma/ministere/resultat.jsp"

payload = "texte2=%2324po8%23%234&txt1=12064608"
headers = {
    'accept': "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
    'origin': "http//bac.menara.ma",
    'user-agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.124 Safari/537.36",
    'content-type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    'referer': "http//bac.menara.ma/ministere/",
    'accept-encoding': "gzip, deflate",
    'accept-language': "en-US,en;q=0.8",
    'cookie': "JSESSIONID=7EF23C675238D7AC936A58CFCA5CBA35; ___utmgb=e#ebzb; __utmt=1; __utma=268890082.1354194921.1434543682.1434543682.1434543682.1; __utmb=268890082.3.10.1434543682; __utmc=268890082; __utmz=268890082.1434543682.1.1.utmcsr=stackoverflow.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/questions/30891272/sending-post-method-manually-using-python"
    }

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: Better to use a `requests.session` than hard-coding the cookie.